# Reshaping MATLAB matrix in a particular way

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I am working on a MATLAB code so that I can basically do this

[image]

To accomlish that, my code looks like this

```
A = [1:30]'; % Example matrix
rows = 3;

for i=1:(numel(A)-rows+1)
    B(1:rows,i)=A(i:i+rows-1,1);
end
```

Can someone help me do the same in a simpler way? I am guessing there is a one-line command that can solve that (maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: Do you have the image processing toolbox?

Comment: Hi Luis, I do but I must say I would prefer not using any toolbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `A` and `rows` be defined as in your code. I'm assuming the values in `A` are just an example. If they are always `1`, `2`, ..., some of the solutions below can be simplified.

```
A = [1:30].';
rows = 3;
```

Here are some approaches:

- My choice:

  ```
  B = A(bsxfun(@plus, (1:rows).', 0:numel(A)-rows));
  ```
- An alternative:

  ```
  B = conv2(A.', flip(eye(rows)));
  B = B(:, rows:end-rows+1);
  ```
- Slightly more inefficient:

  ```
  B = hankel(A);
  B = B(1:rows, 1:numel(A)-rows+1);
  ```
- If you have the Image Processing Toolbox:

  ```
  B = im2col(A, [rows 1], 'sliding');
  ```

Comment: Is that 'sliding' related to a sliding window? If so, that would really help me with other parts of my code.

Comment: @bru1987 [Yes](https://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html), it is

Comment: Amazing. Thank you.

Comment: Luis can you please confirm your "an alternative" code? I am getting a blank matrix for B. Are you experiencing the same?

Comment: @bru1987 Sorry, a transpose was missing. Corrected now

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate that. Have a great day!

Comment: Glad I could help. Same for you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154499/discussion-between-bru1987-and-luis-mendo).

Comment: I'm not fluent in Python, but [here](https://tio.run/##RcyxDsIgFIXhnac4iQs31YEwO9D4FqQDKuqt5NIUlvrySOzg@p0/Z9nqK4ttzeGMxKXqNcgzanO0hggH3EMNCAUB5vILlPTS9uWa8u2Nwp@oxk7eO8/DPOGRV8xgwf4ktBP/KUXRjk4yGJrUsrJUPVJrXw)'s my attempt

Comment: Thank you @Luis, it worked like a charm. Have a great day!